# How to get the Windows host to use the VPN connection from a Hyper-V guest?

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, vpn, hyper-v

From within a Hyper-V guest running Debian 10, I've installed some VPN software and connected to the VPN server.

How can I use the connection my VM client is making with some of the apps running on the host OS (Windows 10)?

- Host OS: Windows 10
- Guest OS: Debian 10

Here's a graphical representation of what I'm trying to achieve:
[image]

I've looked at similar questions but none were about Hyper-V specifically.

Comment: basically, uncheck mgmt OS from external virtual switch, add a 2nd internal virtual switch for host and guest, configure debian as the router, 2nd virtual switch guest<-->host, host traffic goes through debian